# Mysql update takes data only from first row, is it bug?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have query like this:

```
UPDATE `portal_dyslektyczny`.`questions` AS `Question` SET `Question`.`order` = `Question`.`order` - (`Question`.`order` - 3) + 1 WHERE `Question`.`order` > 3 AND `Question`.`question_group_id` = 1;
```

and even though all rows have ascending order like

```
+----+-------+-------------------+
| id | order | question_group_id |
+----+-------+-------------------+
| 74 |     6 |                 1 |
| 75 |     7 |                 1 |
| 76 |     8 |                 1 |
+----+-------+-------------------+
```

but when i run query table ends like this

```
+----+-------+-------------------+
| id | order | question_group_id |
+----+-------+-------------------+
| 74 |     4 |                 1 |
| 75 |     4 |                 1 |
| 76 |     4 |                 1 |
+----+-------+-------------------+
```

as i get it for each row value change should look like this

```
ID: 74

`Question`.`order` = 6 - ( 6 - 3) + 1;

ID: 75

`Question`.`order` = 7 - ( 7 - 3) + 1;
```

so on.

Bu it isn't. It looks like it get values only from first row. Does any one know why?

Comment: echo your SQL query to the browser when you run it and paste the result here so we can take a look.

Comment: Echoed query is in the question on the top. And tables are given, before and after query run.

Comment: So...6-(6-3) + 1 AND 7-(7-3) + 1 AND 8-(8-3) + 1 ALL equal 4. This is no bug, this is arithmetic. IF you were to continue to 100 - (100-3) + 1 still equals 4.

Comment: Damn me, I have to go to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your formula - it resolves to 4 in all cases.

x - (x - 3) + 1 = 4